# Linux mint blocks any incoming connections

Tags: networking, linux-mint, firewall

I'm running `Mint-18` on a computer that it's IP address is on DMZ.

On Windows 10, When running a server, I can access the server using my hostname with no issues But on `Mint` I'm getting `Cannot access error`

`iptables` are not defined and the `firewall` is off. I couldn't find any other reason / mean to block Incoming connections.

More informative: I'm developing a Spring application on tomcat 8  container. I'm trying to access it outside of my development machine (linux-mint) and that is why I enabled DMZ.

*** EDIT ***

For example: My computer is on 10.0.0.1. DMZ is set on 10.0.0.1  - On that machine, I'm running a tomcat server on port *8080*

Let say that my ip 55.44.22.33.

When browsing 55.44.22.33:8080 I'm getting nothing

If I'm running the tomcat server on Windows, everything is working as expected

Any ideas?

Comment: Please add IP addresses to the question, with an indication of which one belongs where. You're quite possibly hitting a hairpin NAT problem.

Comment: "_When browsing 55.44.22.33:8080 I'm getting nothing_" is this browsing happening from a machine on your 10. network, or from another system out there in the Internet? Please try it from another system - maybe from a friend's, or something, to confirm that you've set up Port Forwarding on your NAT Router correctly.

Comment: From another system out there in the internet. an external server is trying to communicate with my server without success.

Comment: 1. You say tomcat works on a Windows system. During this test is the Windows system temporarily given the same IP address as the Linux system? 2. Can you reach the tomcat server at 10.0.0.1:8080 from another system on your LAN? 3. Does your Mint system have a default route via the NAT router to the Internet (e.g. can it `ping 8.8.8.8`? What is output of `netstat -rn`?)

Answer (score -1):

How are you trying to access this server? By default Linux mint has ssh **off**. In fact, I think ICMP is the only thing it will respond to out of the box. You will need to install an ssh server and turn it on if you wish to ssh. Likewise if you wish to connect via 80 or 443, you will need to install an http server and turn it on. Since you did not specify how you are connecting (telnet? ssh? http? ftp? nfs? samba? smpt? the list is long...) I can not help you further. You also specify it is on the DMZ. Are your inbound rules for the server the same as they are for the windows host?

You can find explicit instructions for installing and starting ssh/etc for Mint online if you have not installed and started the service for how you want to connect.

Comment: Trying to connect using http. more informative: I'm developing a Spring application on tomcat 8  container. I'm trying to access it outside of my development machine (linux-mint) and that is why I enabled DMZ. Thanks